# DirectX C# Custom Mesh

Tags: c#, directx, mesh, managed

Struggling to get this custom mesh working. The result on the GUI form is a red cross on a white background (DirectX device error). I can easily get Mesh.Box or Mesh.Sphere working but the attempt to create a custom Mesh fails.
I have looked through numerous examples, but still no joy.

Hope you can help.

```
    private Mesh meshSubject = null;

    int numberVerts = 36;
    short[] indices = { 
        0,1,2, // Front Face  
        1,3,2, // Front Face  
        4,5,6, // Back Face  
        6,5,7, // Back Face  
        0,5,4, // Top Face  
        0,2,5, // Top Face  
        1,6,7, // Bottom Face  
        1,7,3, // Bottom Face  
        0,6,1, // Left Face  
        4,6,0, // Left Face  
        2,3,7, // Right Face  
        5,2,7 // Right Face  
    };

private void OnDeviceReset(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // THESE TEST MESHES WORK
     //meshSubject = Mesh.Box(device, 0.8f, 0.18f, 2.2f);
     //meshSubject = Mesh.Sphere(device, 0.5f, 8,1000);

    // **** start of custom mesh - THIS CUSTOM MESH DOES NOT WORK :-(
    Mesh meshSubject = new Mesh(indices.Length / 3, numberVerts, MeshFlags.Managed, CustomVertex.PositionColored.Format, device);

    IndexBuffer indicesBuff = meshSubject.IndexBuffer;
    VertexBuffer verticesBuff = meshSubject.VertexBuffer;

    GraphicsStream data = verticesBuff.Lock(0, 0, LockFlags.None);

    data.Write(new CustomVertex.PositionColored(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0x00ff00ff));
    data.Write(new CustomVertex.PositionColored(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0x00ff00ff));
    data.Write(new CustomVertex.PositionColored(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0x00ff00ff));
    data.Write(new CustomVertex.PositionColored(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0x00ff00ff));
    data.Write(new CustomVertex.PositionColored(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 0x00ff00ff));
    data.Write(new CustomVertex.PositionColored(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 0x00ff00ff));
    data.Write(new CustomVertex.PositionColored(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 0x00ff00ff));
    data.Write(new CustomVertex.PositionColored(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 0x00ff00ff));

    verticesBuff.Unlock();              

    indicesBuff.SetData(indices, 0, LockFlags.None);

    device.SetStreamSource(0, verticesBuff, 0);

    //**** end of custom mesh *******************

    device.RenderState.Ambient = Color.White;

    device.Lights[0].Type = LightType.Directional;
    device.Lights[0].Direction = new Vector3(0.3f, -0.5f, 0.2f);
    device.Lights[0].Diffuse = Color.White;
    device.Lights[0].Update();

    device.Lights[1].Type = LightType.Directional;
    device.Lights[1].Direction = new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, -3.0f);
    device.Lights[1].Diffuse = Color.White;
    device.Lights[1].Update();

    device.Lights[0].Enabled = true;
    device.Lights[1].Enabled = true;

    device.Transform.Projection = Matrix.PerspectiveFovLH((float)Math.PI / 5.0F, (float)this.ClientSize.Width / (float)this.ClientSize.Height, 2.0f, 80.0f);
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    //Render();
    Form.ActiveForm.Update();

    device.BeginScene();

    device.VertexFormat = CustomVertex.TransformedColored.Format;

    Color meshColor = Color.White;

    Material material = new Material();

    // Begin the scene and clear the back buffer to black.
    device.Clear(ClearFlags.Target | ClearFlags.ZBuffer, Color.Black, 1.0f, 0);

    SetupMatrices();

    meshSubject.DrawSubset(0);

    device.VertexFormat = CustomVertex.PositionNormal.Format;

    device.DrawPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 12);

    device.Lights[2].Enabled = true;

    material.Diffuse = Color.Olive;
    device.Material = material;

    device.EndScene();
    device.Present();

    this.Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: What does the debug output say? Are there any exceptions? It seems like you're just beginning. Is there any reason why you use DX9?

Comment: Hi Nico, There is no output from debug or exceptions, I am just beginning my journey in 3D graphics programming. The reason to use DX9 is due to having a book for several years. I see the problem in my code where the Mesh is null. I don't know how to make the Mesh object public to the functions which need it. The DX C# book I have only explains how to load a Mesh from file .x format and use it in a basic 3D space game. I would really like to code custom Meshes, but I have found only fragments of examples. I'd prefer to use OpenGL but I paid money for the book so like to learn directx method.

Comment: Oh, you have two `Mesh` variables. On as a field in the class and a second one in the method `OnDeviceReset`. The latter hides the former one. Just remove the declaration and you should be fine (just write `meshSubject = new Mesh(...`.

Comment: Unfortunately the Mesh object requires the indices array so it cannot exist outside of a function or non-static field. 
Mesh meshSubject = new Mesh(indices.Length / 3, numberVerts, MeshFlags.Managed, CustomVertex.PositionColored.Format, device);

Comment: What do you mean? You have the `private Mesh meshSubject` as a class field and a second `Mesh meshSubject = new Mesh(...)` in the method, although you want to reference the field from the method. Therefore, remove the additional declaration and just use `meshSubject = new Mesh(...)` in the method.

Comment: @NicoSchertler
 There is no class. If the class is the way to go to make meshSubject = new Mesh(...) public, I don't know how to do that. I would like to 
replace ...
**bold**"private Mesh meshSubject" **bold**
with 
**bold**" Mesh meshSubject = new Mesh(indices.Length / 3, numberVerts, MeshFlags.Managed, CustomVertex.PositionColored.Format, device);" **bold**
But cannot because the compiler throws this error: Error 1 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property

Comment: There must be a class or a structure. The first line `private Mesh meshSubject = null;` cannot exist on its own. You should not replace *this* occurence of `meshSubject` but the one in the `OnDeviceReset` method.

Comment: I have tried those. A class or struct will not work because meshSubject requires parameters which cannot exist outside a method. Another thing I have tried ...
public Mesh meshSubject; 
with 
meshSubject = new Mesh(...Parameters...);
in the InitializeGraphic() function (this simply sets the device)
The Mesh object is passed in to the so it should work. There must be something else wrong here.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Hi Buddy. I solved the issue ...
The mesh object has to be reinstated inside the OnDeviceReset, so I cloned it. I did not see a solution for this but was just a hunch.
Within OnDeviceReset I wrote...
meshSubject = meshSubject.Clone(meshSubject.Options.Value,meshSubject.VertexFormat | VertexFormats.Normal,device);

Comment: @NicoSchertler How do I marked this question as solved and add Thanks ?!

Comment: Good that you solved it. Post an answer and accept it so mark the question as solved. Or since the question probably won't help any other users, you could delete the question altogether. Btw, there must have been a NullReferenceException. It is odd that you didn't notice that.

Comment: Hi @NicoSchertler. There was no NullReferenceException flagged up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mesh object seems to need reinstating inside the OnDeviceReset, so I cloned it. I did not see a solution for this on the internet but was just a hunch. Within OnDeviceReset I wrote... 
meshSubject = meshSubject.Clone(meshSubject.Options.Value,meshSubject.VertexFormat | VertexFormats.Normal,device);